# Time between two events

Tags: sql, postgresql

If have got a table that tracks some events of a user.

```
 id | user_id | action |         created_at         
----+---------+--------+----------------------------
  5 |       1 | create | 2016-09-08 11:29:56.325691
  6 |       1 | clear  | 2016-09-08 11:30:00.08604
  7 |       2 | create | 2016-09-08 11:30:10.12857
  8 |       2 | clear  | 2016-09-08 11:30:14.238685
  9 |       3 | create | 2016-09-08 11:30:42.192843
```

There is always a `create` action that might be followed by a `clear` action.

```
CREATE TYPE user_actions AS ENUM ('create', 'clear');
```

Now I want to query the time difference between these two actions to get the time_diff between the `create` and `clear` of a user.

For now you can assume that the `user` doesn't have multiple entries (e.g. at least one `create` and maximal another `clear`).

I would like to have a result like this:

```
 user_id |    time_diff    
---------+-----------------
       1 | 00:00:03.760349
       2 | 00:00:04.110115
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT user_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN action = 'clear' THEN created_at END) -
       MAX(CASE WHEN action = 'create' THEN created_at END) AS time_diff 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY user_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

The `HAVING` clause filters out `user_id` groups containing only a `create` action, like record with `id=9` in the OP.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/aa88a/1)

Comment: Thank you. This works great and is what I was looking for. One thing that I don't understand is why I need the `MAX()`.

Comment: @Mark `MAX()` is needed because of the `GROUP BY`: any field of the `SELECT` clause that is not contained in the `GROUP BY` clause has to be used inside an aggregate function.

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know! I had this problem quiet a few times the last days. Now I know how to avid this - great!!!