# Subtracting datetime items based on some conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm learning about SQL using SQL Server 2016 Express. I am building an app and using databases to monitor user activity. For every button click I log an `activity_type` and the datetime with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

```
SELECT activity_type, occurred_at 
FROM user_activity
```

This returns the following example data

```
activity_type         occurred_at       
 ------------------- ---------------------- 
LogIn                3/7/2019 9:27:58 AM   
Action1              3/7/2019 9:27:59 AM   
Action2              3/7/2019 9:28:00 AM   
LogOut               3/7/2019 9:28:01 AM   
LogIn                3/7/2019 9:28:02 AM   
LogIn                3/7/2019 9:28:04 AM
```

I want to calculate the total time elapsed of the activities between each Login and Logout. LogOut activity might not be needed at all. I can consider the last activity before any LogIn as the logout time.

My expected answer here would be the time between the 1st LogIn and Action2, and  0 for the 2nd and 3rd LogIn with no activity in between them.

Any ideas of how can I solve this problem? Thanks!

Updates on answer:

The answer provided by @Gordon worked

The results are:

```
        Column1               Column2         dur_seconds  
 --------------------- --------------------- ------------- 
  03/07/2019 09:27:58   03/07/2019 09:28:00             2  
  03/07/2019 09:28:06   03/07/2019 09:28:06             0  
  03/07/2019 09:28:08   03/07/2019 09:28:08             0  
  03/07/2019 10:28:12   03/07/2019 10:28:12             0  
  03/07/2019 10:38:55   03/07/2019 10:38:55             0  
  03/07/2019 10:40:09   03/07/2019 10:40:09             0  
  03/07/2019 10:40:46   03/07/2019 10:40:46             0  
  03/07/2019 10:42:23   03/07/2019 10:49:28           425  
  03/07/2019 10:51:15   03/07/2019 10:57:49           394  
  03/07/2019 10:57:55   03/07/2019 10:59:02            67
```

Comment: I don't see your attempt to self-solve. Dumping task requirements as a "question" is not encouraged here.  Volunteers are meant to fix your code, not provide new development work for free.  Your question is Too Broad.  Please include evidence that you have conducted research and tried something before posting a question.  [ask]

Comment: Please provide the results as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time between two events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39387712/time-between-two-events)

Comment: @mickmackusa Thank you four comment, I will provide more evidence next time.

Comment: @EricBrandt Thanks, Indeed it was duplicate. Couldn't find it earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky.  You want to use `group by`, but there is no grouping column.  So, you can create one -- by counting the number of login records up to each record.

Then:

```
select min(occurred_at), max(occurred_at),
       datediff(second, min(occurred_at), max(occurred_at)) as dur_seconds
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when activity_type = 'LogIn' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by occurred_at) as grp
      from t
     ) t
where activity_type <> 'LogOut'
group by grp;
```

Comment: Thank you, this one worked. Trying to post the results now.