# SQL Time Between Two Events

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to expand on the solution from: [Time between two events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39387712/time-between-two-events)

Given the following table, I want to be able to find the time difference when a action changes from `clear` to `create`. As you can see, an item might `clear` several times before it `create`.

Additionally, the event may happen several times for one user and I would like to capture the time difference each time it occurs.

```
 id | user_id | action |         created_at         
----+---------+--------+----------------------------
  5 |       1 | clear  | 2016-09-08 11:29:56
  6 |       1 | create | 2016-09-08 11:30:00
  7 |       2 | create | 2016-09-08 11:30:10
  8 |       2 | clear  | 2016-09-08 11:30:14
  9 |       2 | clear  | 2016-09-08 11:30:42
  10|       2 | create | 2016-09-08 11:30:43
  11|       2 | clear  | 2016-09-08 11:30:47
  12|       2 | create | 2016-09-08 11:30:55
```

Desired output (changes between id 5-6, id 9-10, id 11-12):

```
 user_id |    time_diff    
---------+-----------------
       1 | 00:00:03
       2 | 00:00:01
       2 | 00:00:08
```

Using the following code I am only able to extract the most recent time diff and not all of them:

```
SELECT user_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN action = 'create' THEN created_at END) -
       MAX(CASE WHEN action = 'clear' THEN created_at END) AS time_diff 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY user_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You `lead()`:

```
select user_id, (next_created_at - created_at)
from (select t.*,
              lead(action) over (partition by user_id order by created_at) as next_action,
              lead(created_at) over (partition by user_id order by created_at) as next_created_at
      from t
     ) t
where next_action = 'clear' and action = 'create';
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/aa88a/38) is a SQL fiddle.

In older versions of MySQL, you can use correlated subqueries to get the next value:

```
select user_id, (next_created_at - created_at)
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.action
              from t t2
              where t2.user_id = t.user_id and
                    t2.created_at > t.created_at
              order by t2.created_at
              limit 1
             ) as next_action,
             (select t2.created_at
              from t t2
              where t2.user_id = t.user_id and
                    t2.created_at > t.created_at
              order by t2.created_at
              limit 1
             ) as next_created_at
      from t
     ) t
where next_action = 'clear' and action = 'create';
```

Comment: Hey Gordon, this doesn't seem to work. You can test it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/aa88a/1

Comment: @ohoh7171 . . . Thank you for setting up the fiddle!  In the fiddle, the "create" comes before the "clear"; the question suggests that these are in the opposite order.  I changed the answer based on the fiddle, rather than the question.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I am getting a syntax error potentially because the MySQL version of the database is too old. Any other suggestions?